# IOS Element not moving when frame updated the first time but moves on the second update

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have an object of type `UINavigationBar` that I'm trying to reposition when a `UITextField` object triggers it's `Editing Did Begin` event. However I'm running into a strange error where when the following code is called:

```
- (IBAction)prepForTabBarView:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Test");
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    CGFloat navBarPosition = screenHeight - 350 - 64;

    [self.navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,  navBarPosition, screenWidth , 44)];
}
```

The first time the event is called the navBar doesn't move however the second time it's called the navBar moves. However both times the NSLog appears. What's going on here? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Is `navBar` created in Interface Builder or does it have any layout constraints on it?

Comment: It has constraints to keep it the width of the window. I have tried to remove all constraints from the navBar element to see if that was the issue but the same thing still happens.

Comment: how are you removing the constraints?  Because if you're using a storyboard or xib there are implicit constraints often added at build time for you.

Comment: I'm deleting them by the size inspector.

Comment: That's probably not good enough.  You'll want to programmatically remove them just to be sure.

Comment: Either that or try building the navBar in code.